# How can I write this kind of logic in a most usable way?

Tags: php

I am asking this question to know, is there other best way to write this logic in a minimum of lines?

This is my code with lot of `if` and `elseif` conditions:

```
if ($emission <= 100 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_a"; 
} elseif ($emission > 101 && $emission <= 120 ){
    $cssClass = "emission_b";
} elseif ($emission >= 121 && $emission <= 150 ){
    $cssClass = "emission_c";
} elseif ($emission >= 151 && $emission <= 165 ){
    $cssClass = "emission_d";
} elseif ($emission >= 166 && $emission <= 185 ){
    $cssClass = "emission_e";
} elseif ($emission >= 186 && $emission <= 125 ){
    $cssClass = "emission_f";
} elseif ($emission >= 226){
    $cssClass = "emission_g";
}
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: keyword: associative array

Comment: @Rizier123. you mean? can you elaborate it? Thank you.

Comment: You can remove all the conditions before the && (i.e. `$emission > 101 && `) because every time you get to the next check it was already determined that the value is above the previous. So you only really need to do `if ($emission <= 100 ) { $cssClass = "emission_a"; } elseif ($emission <= 120 ){...` if that make sense.

Comment: @mic someone just took your comment and posted it as an answer....mmmhh interesting

Comment: lol that's usually the way lol

Answer (score 4):

You could spare some chars if you simplified the conditions, but you will need the same amount of if/elseif statements

```
<?php

if ($emission <= 100 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_a"; 
} elseif ($emission <= 120 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_b";
} elseif ($emission <= 150 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_c";
} elseif ($emission <= 165 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_d";
} elseif ($emission <= 185 ) {
    $cssClass = "emission_e";
} else {
    $cssClass = "emission_g";
} 

// this one makes no sense, maybe a typo?
// } elseif ($emission >= 186 && $emission <= 125 ){
```

Or you try it with an mapping array like this

```
<?php
$mapping = array(
    100 => 'emission_a',
    120 => 'emission_b',
    150 => 'emission_c',
    165 => 'emission_d',
    185 => 'emission_e',
    225 => 'emission_f'
);

$cssClass = 'emission_g'; // default class if $emission is > 225

foreach ($mapping as $limit => $class) {
    if ($emission <= $limit) {
        $cssClass = $class;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Effectively the same answer as given by @mic in the comments.

Comment: its not the same, i found a possible typo and replaced an elseif with an else... and to calm you down i added an other possible solution. users have to post answers as answers... i could not comment with my low reputation.

Comment: That's true, and kuddos for your alternative solution; quite elegant. +1 from me.